# Broadcast receiver onReceive() never called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I get this issue in ICS, but not in previous versions:

From App1, I am sending broadcast and trying to receive it in App 2 activity. But the onReceive is never called in App 2's activity.

I cannot understand what is that block's onReceive from getting called, though I have specified everything correctly.

I run the BroadcastReceive first and then BroadcastSend

Any help which would help me resolve this is much appreciated.

App1 send activity

```
public class BroadcastSend extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction("edu.ius.rwisman.custom.intent.action.TEST");
    i.putExtra("url","ww.ius.edu");
    sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

App 2 receive activity

```
public class BroadcastReceive extends BroadcastReceiver{
// Display an alert that we've received a message.    
@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    System.out.println("Inside onReceive");
    String url = intent.getExtras().getString("url");
    Toast.makeText(context, "BroadcastReceive:"+url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Manifest of App 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:name="edu.ius.rwisman.BroadcastReceive.BroadcastReceive" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="edu.ius.rwisman.custom.intent.action.TEST"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ICS you won't receive broadcasts until your app is started manually at least once.in Android 3.1+, apps are in a stopped state if they have never been run, or have been force stopped. The system excludes these apps from broadcast intents. They can be included by using the Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag like this..

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
```

Comment: thanks that this fixed the issue. but we first run the receive activity and then the send activity. then why we faced this issue?

Comment: Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but are not yet launched and when they are manually stopped by the user (in Manage Applications)... see this http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

Comment: but how include this flag in manifest when registering broadcast

Comment: @ShahjahanKhan why would you need to register a flag for the sender-broadcast? You need to do this only in code as the sender doesn't need to register anything in manifest, only the receiver. And if I understand it correctly, this flag is only relevant for the OS-side of Android to select the app-instances for which this broadcast will be triggered.