# unable to receive ACTION_TIME_CHANGED intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am not able to receive the `ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` intent in my `broadcast receiver` class when I change the time from the phone. Is there anything in particular that I need to add in android.manifest?

I have already added

in broadcast receiver class:

```
else if((intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED)) ||(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED ))){ 
    Log.d("ContactsAppReceiver", "ACTION_TIME_CHANGED");
}
```

And in manifest.xml file. :

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED"/>
```

Comment: which version of android are you using?

Comment: why should that matter? its not the newest one..

Comment: it matters because.. see this answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783704/broadcast-receiver-onreceive-never-called/9784004#9784004

Answer (score 2):

Add to manifest:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
```