# Broadcast receiver android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to start service on Boot completion, After doing lot digging I have found nothing.

Very first approach that I have tried was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20441442/5476209), I found this approach in most answers, but it doesn't work.

Then I have found that this approach is not working on 3.1+ from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19856367/5476209)

I have also seen this, https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

and used **FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES** also in my code.I have referred this approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9783704/5476209).

### AndroidMenifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/security"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

    <receiver android:name="com.reversebits.projects.app.easyerase.receiver.BootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="myReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".services.BootService"
        android:enabled="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.reversebits.projects.app.easyerase.services.BootService"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </service>

</application>
```

### BootReciever

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public BootReceiver() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
        {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, BootService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

### BootService

```
public class BootService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //TODO do something useful Recommended by google instead of onStart()
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        loopThread();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    void loopThread() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
                    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                        Log.e("MyApp", "Silent mode");
                        break;
                    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                        Log.e("MyApp", "Vibrate mode");
                        break;
                    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                        Log.e("MyApp", "Normal mode");
                        break;

                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                loopThread();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

**Code works perfect and i got all logs when service is starting from activity, but on Boot complete, it is not working**

**Note:** 
I have read almost all related answers and on some answers,I have also read comments and I know almost all related things, so please do not provide me other links, as  have seen most of them already, I need the perfect solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try adding 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/> another action

Comment: okay @NayanSrivastava

Comment: still not working @NayanSrivastava

Comment: did you check permissions?

Comment: yes of cource !! You can see menifest file code @RushiAyyappa

Comment: What device are you testing this on? Have you tried other devices?

Comment: It's Xolo Q510s , With Kitkat 4.4.2 flavour @DavidWasser

Comment: First, remove the `permission` attribute from the `<receiver>` element. Then, make sure that you're running your `Activity` at least once after installation, before rebooting. And, if you're testing on a device, be aware that some OEMs restrict apps from running at startup by default. You'll need to look in your settings - or possibly in any security-related apps it might have - to see if that's the case. Also note that it may take up to several minutes for your Receiver to actually get the boot broadcast.

Comment: Just a suggestion. In the future, if you don't want to get downvotes, do not tell people to "read it all before downvoting". Do not write "all my code works perfectly except...". Do not write "I have read all the answers and comments so please don't post links to them". This makes you come across as an arrogant know-it-all, but since you have a problem you want us to help you solve, you obviously don't know it all. So in the future, when asking a question, try to be humble. It will save you some downvotes.

Comment: okay @MikeM. I have removed , and after waiting for some minutes, it's still not receiving broadcast, but how can i check it in my settings? Should i add Admin authority in my app ?

Comment: On some devices there is a separate security settings screen where you need to explicitly enable apps to be started at boot time. It also seems that there are some devices that just refuse to start 3rd party applications at boot, for whatever reason. I strongly suggest that you find another device to test on to be sure.

Comment: Just remember, you are asking us to help you. For free (without having to pay for it). Think about that for a minute.

Comment: @DavidWasser not working on Samsung device also, It has jelly bin flovour, but not working at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedIntentReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".Service"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

    </service>
```

yo

```
          public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, Service.class);

        context.startService(pushIntent);}
```

and dont forget

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

service

```
public class BootService extends Service {
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    //TODO do something useful Recommended by google instead of onStart()
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                    Log.e("MyApp", "Silent mode");
                    break;
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                    Log.e("MyApp", "Vibrate mode");
                    break;
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                    Log.e("MyApp", "Normal mode");
                    break;

            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();
}




@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
  }
```

Comment: this is not working at all, have tried that very first @Dr.Easy

Comment: i created a service and receiver this 2 days and it works great :O

Comment: i wanted to help u downvoted me thx

Comment: put the thread inside onStart like i did in my app but with try and catch

Comment: can you show me in code where? @Dr.Easy

Comment: check the updated edit

Comment: did it help ???